# Creating User Profiles

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Pretty new to rails, and coding in general. I'm working on my own app right now, in which I'm trying to create user profiles. I know that there have been a few questions about this, but what I'm specifically trying to do is...

Upon authentication (which I've set up using Devise), the user is redirected to his/her profile page where he/she can set up their own profile, with fields similar to what you may find on a social networking website.

I'm running rails 4.1 and ruby 2.1 right now. Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to go about doing this. As I mentioned I'm fairly new to rails, and have spent the last few days furiously searching for advice on the internet.

Does anyone know of a step by step guide?

I suppose what I need is just guidance on where to start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

recently i created user profile so that user can add/edit his personal details,see what he has uploaded.what he has liked,posted and edit/delete/update anything that he has created/uploaded.So in user profile all you need is to fetch all details/associated models of that user and show.*So as u already have devise..you can get current_user and use user.rb model to understand all associations of user and get the data using associations ans display it on profile page*

i have created a `profile_controller`
so in my nav_bar i have a link_to `<% link_to "View Profile",show_profile_path(current_user) %>`

where user is directed to profiles controller and i show the details **without** creating a new model(`user has_one :profile`)

i have a dedicated page to show profile details + a small page to show any user profile when hovered on users image

take a look here for view side idea...  [user profile page on bootstrap 3](http://www.bootply.com/fzYmNbNQOx)

**=======updated part===========**

suppose i have a `user.rb`(using `devise`)

```
###different associations of user can be:=
 ##this user can like/dislike any model having acts_as_votable
acts_as_voter
##user can tags post/audio/videos/images
acts_as_tagger
##my user can create post,pages,upload images/videos/songs/locations etc...
has_many :posts, :class_name => 'Post', :dependent => :destroy
has_many :pages, :class_name => 'Page', :dependent => :destroy
has_many :images, :class_name => 'Image', :dependent => :destroy
has_many :videos, :class_name => 'Video', :dependent => :destroy
has_many :audios, :class_name => 'Audio', :dependent => :destroy
has_many :places, :class_name => 'Place', :dependent => :destroy
has_many :profile_pictures, :class_name => 'ProfilePicture', :dependent => :destroy


#####so..as now i know that **my user can have post/pages/audios/videos** etc...i can also get the details about those associations(assuming you have configured belongs_to in associated models as well + tables with foreign_key as user_id in eash associtated table),such as:-*

##to get all  videos that user has uploaded
@user.videos
##same applies for other associated models as well
@user.images..@user.audios...@user.pages.....@user.post....@user.places...@user.profile_pictures...etc
####So now you have all user(current_user data)...
###its time to show data in profiles_controller..
##your show method
## profile#show
def show
@user=User.find current_user.id
@all_user_videos=@user.videos..and so on
##get all user videos/images..etc and show it in your view file
##your view file can be the one that i shared the link or any other way that you want...
###there are lot of ways...google around and then you can get an idea as how to display user_profile page..as now you have the data(*Yipee*)

end##method ends
```

*hope this helps*

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So using this method, what are the different controllers/models/views that are needed? Is it just one of each?

Comment: @user3785435...i have added more info...go through it ..hope this is enough to get u an idea of how to start

Comment: Can you please add your rake routes so that I can see how to piece it all together? Also, do you have your app redirect to a profile creation form after sign up?

Comment: hi @user3785435...you can ask user to enter profile details like name,sex,occupation,address and hobbies during signup or later as well.For routes.rb...just create a new resource or scaffold for `profile`

Answer (score 1):

You can add other fields like first name, last name, and date of birth to user table itself if you have minimum number of attributes you want to add. You can get all the details from `current_user`. But if you have many fields that you want to add to user profile then you can create a new model name `UserProfile` and add other related fields to this model. And add a `one-to-one` relationship between `User` and `UserProfile` table. So in the future if you want to add another relation/attribute with/to user, you can add it with `UserProfile`. That will reduce making a mess in your database in later stages.